# Build just one (lazy loaded) module in angular2

Tags: angular, build, lazy-loading

Is there any possible way to build just one module from an angular app?
I want to use one of the lazy loaded modules as a separate app, and as a part of the main app as well.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really possible to use the same module as both a separate (root) module and a feature module in another application (https://angular.io/guide/module-types), as this would result in bootstrapping the application twice.

However, it should be possible to get very close to this behavior; simply import the lazy-loaded feature module as a non-lazy loaded feature module in a separate root module (this is really only ~100LOC, just for bootstrapping).

Comment: In fact i would like to build the priject 2 different ways: first build the whole app, whith that component (thats not a question, i know how to do it), but second i want to build an app which contains just that special module (+ shared and core modules). Is there any way to achive this? I'm about to copy the whole app, and delete the other modules from it, than build that again. Does it makes any sense?